# How to do a geometric search using latitude and longitude using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Did any know about how to search using latitude and longitude using latitude and longitude
using php and mysql as back-end.

I am having zip-code and latitude and longitude for the corresponding city.

If i enter for a search with latitude i need to know the name of the city with that corresponding latitude and longitude.

With these things as back-end how can i do my search.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate. What are you searching for? What is stored in the database? What have you tried doing?

Comment: Why do you think it would be different from searching say a name or ph number ?

Comment: @unicornaddict I fully understand that the OP hasn't put much in to this, but a true geospatial search requirement isn't the same as searching a name or ph number.

Comment: @adam: could you please explain me the requirement of geospatial search. thanks

Comment: It's not my question but as an example by storing lat/long pairs geospatially you could define a polygon and get all the rows that lie within.

Comment: Why are you repeating yourself twice twice?

Answer (score 3):

You'd be wanting a GeoSpatial database to do true geometric searches. There's a chapter about it in the MySQL manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-introduction.html